# После записи данные не видны из-за ошибки в подключении к БД

Tags: python, sql, oracle, cx-oracle

Вот код для отправки записи:

```
cursor = create_connection()
sql = """INSERT INTO AUTHORS (name,sername,phone, email) VALUES ('IVAN', 'PETROV', '89624625137', 'IVANPETROV@yandex.ru')"""
cursor.execute(sql)
sql = "SELECT name FROM AUTHORS"

for row in cursor.execute(sql):
    print(row)

def create_connection():
    connection = cx_Oracle.connect("SYSTEM", 'xfZrvmBVyFs=1', 
    "172.20.0.2:1521/ORCLCDB", encoding="UTF-8")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
```

И после того как запрос выполнен, если подключиться через SQL Developer, то в ней не будет записей. Соответственно, если добавить запись в SQL Developer то ее нельзя будет считать из Python. Видимо ошибка в подключении к БД. Сам сервер установлен на docker.

Как правильно подключиться?

Comment: Хмм, "а компот?" (ц), то есть commit.

Comment: да,только что прочитал. connection.commit()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По умолчанию cx_Oracle не [фиксирует изменения](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/txn_management.html) автоматически:

> By default, cx_Oracle does not commit this transaction to the database. The methods `Connection.commit()` and `Connection.rollback()` methods can be used to explicitly commit or rollback a transaction

Как алтернатива, можно включить [*auto-commit*](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/txn_management.html#autocommitting), но это не всегда наилучшее решение:

```
connection.autocommit = True
```